# Is there a way to connect succesfully in Alexa with alexapy.AlexaLogin consistently?

Tags: python

I have found a library that says that it can execute programmatically Alexa devices (alexapy). I use the most simple form of connection (I create the class with URL, name, password and method to store output, then I use login() method with the preconfigured arguments and ask if the connection has been done) And it can happen three things: or it connects successful (rarely), or it not connects or it stays frozen (I think that the method test_loggedin() is at fault).

Does anyone know of a way that consistently gives you the same result? Preferably a correct connection.

```
import asyncio

import alexapy

url = 'amazon_url'
name = 'my_username'
password='my_password'

def fun_outputpath(file:str):
     return file

async def connect():
     connect=alexapy.AlexaLogin(url,name,password,fun_outputpath)
     await connect.login()
     isconnected= await connect.test_loggedin()
     if isconnected:
         print("Connected")
     else:
         print("Not connected")
     connect.close()

asyncio.run(connect())
```

I expected that It would print Connected in the terminal, however sometimes freezes, others I got a Runtime Error and others it prints Not connected. I believe that most of the time the execution freezes in the line isconnected= await conect.test_loggedin().

If anyone is interested in helping me you could read https://alexapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alexapy/alexapy.html#classes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a few issues in your code that might be causing the inconsistent behavior and errors.

Typo: You have a typo in your code. You defined the connect function, but you are trying to call methods on conect, which is not defined. You should use the connect object that you created earlier.

asyncio Event Loop: You should run the event loop using asyncio.run() from within a function, not at the module level. This means you should put the call to asyncio.run(connect()) inside a function, such as main(), and then call main().

Here's the corrected code:

```
import asyncio
import alexapy

url = 'amazon_url'
name = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'

def fun_outputpath(file: str):
    return file

async def connect():
    alexa_login = alexapy.AlexaLogin(url, name, password, fun_outputpath)
    await alexa_login.login()
    is_connected = await alexa_login.test_loggedin()
    if is_connected:
        print("Connected")
    else:
        print("Not connected")
    await alexa_login.close()

def main():
    asyncio.run(connect())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for showing me the typo. But it is not in the original code. So the problem persists. If you have read the question you would have seen that I get a return and the error never appears as a SyntaxisError (the typo you have mentioned). So I ask again how do I solve this problem that I have.